# Typescript generic to keep argument types

Tags: typescript, generics, arguments

I have a type for function with any arguments, but there are no warnings and hints for this.

```js
type TThunkAction = (...payload: any) => (dispatch: () => void) => void

const action: TThunkAction = (id: number, text: string) => (dispatch) => {}
action('123', false) // not warning
```

I could use argument as single object:

```js
type TThunkAction<TPayload = any> = (payload?: TPayload) => (dispatch: () => void) => void

const action: TThunkAction<{id: number, text: string}> = ({id, text}) => (dispatch) => {}
action({id: 123, ... // strong types
```

But I would like to use exactly something like "rest parameters". Is there any way to do the generic for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understood what you want to do but if you want to be able to specify the types of multiple arguments to a function, you may do so:

```js
type TThunkAction<TArgs extends unknown[]> = (...payload: TArgs) => (dispatch: () => void) => void

const action: TThunkAction<[number, string]> = (id, text) => (dispatch) => {}
action('123', false) // warning
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKjAWBXAdgawIIGNgEsD2yAPDOgE4DmAzlBAB7ATIAm1KqyeA7sgNoC6APigBeKAAoAdFLABDEABs8MpgC5YZKgEoRQsUxyVZwTPDVjtwoQDc8OJheu2mAKGeYClYFBnZ8yNXBIaFi4BIQ8yIgAtgBGEKQANFCepDjI5IIi4nZJDPQO4vqGMsbwBQDeAL7OPqHIYgDkAIwATADMDUkAZjLylBDaAPSDUJwypMhp5EA)

Comment: I want to declare parameter types via classic way `const action: TThunkAction = (id: number, text: string) => ...`. But I don't know how to make `TThunkAction` detect them automatically

Comment: @FelAA You can't. Type annotations "overwrite" any existing type information. So when you do that, you lose the parameter names and their associated types.

Comment: But since you only need to specify types once, I guess it's more or less okay.